# AndroBugs scan turning up non secure URL's in my APK after installing Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, security, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-security

I installed Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) in my android app.  An AdroBugs scan of my app file turns up some non secure URLs now:

[Critical]  SSL Connection Checking:
           URLs that are NOT under SSL (Total:3):

http://localhost
                   => 
Lcom/google/firebase/auth/api/model/VerifyAssertionRequest;->(Ljava/lang/String; Ljava/lang/String;
                    Ljava/lang/String; Ljava/lang/String; Ljava/lang/String;)V

http://plus.google.com/
                   => Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzp;->()V

http://www.google.com
                   => Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzjh$zza;->(Landroid/content/Context;)V

Does anybody know anything about this?

Comment: Simply decompile the app yourself (e.g. using Jadx) and you will see if or if not those strings are used and for what purpose. If they are not used you may be able to remove the code parts via ProGuard.